# Android Activity/PreferenceFragment lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a very simple preferences setup in which a `PreferenceFragment` is added to an `Activity`. The `Activity` is also an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, since I want to update the summary of a particular preference whenever that preference is updated. Here's the `Activity`:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String PREF_KEY = "key goes here";

    private PrefsFragment pf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pf = new PrefsFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, pf).commit();
        // pf.getPreferenceScreen() throws a NullPointerException here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateSummary();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if (key.equals(PREF_KEY)) {         
            updateSummary();
        }
    }

    private void updateSummary() {
        Preference p = pf.getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_KEY);
        p.setSummary("Some string containing the updated value");
    }

}
```

The PreferenceFragment is equally simple:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        // At this point getPreferenceScreen() returns correctly
    }

}
```

Here's the thing: Calling `getPreferenceScreen()` on the `PreferenceFragment`, immediately after it's been instantiated and added to the `Activity` in `onCreate` of `PrefsActivity`, throws a `NullPointerException`. It seems that `getPreferenceScreen()` starts returning a `PreferenceScreen` object in `onCreate()` of `PrefsFragment`, immediately after the call to `addPreferencesFromResource()` returns.

So my question is this: Since `getPreferenceScreen()` throws an NPE immediately after the `PreferenceFragment` has been added to the `Activity`, is the `onCreate()` of the `PreferenceFragment` called asynchronously/in a different thread? Otherwise I would have expected `getPreferenceScreen()` to return normally immediately after `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, pf).commit()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is the onCreate() of the PreferenceFragment called asynchronously/in a
>   different thread?

No, it is run synchronously on the main thread.  That means it has to wait until the `Activity`s `onCreate` exits before it gets to run.  The `FragmentManager`  schedules the `Fragment` callbacks, but they are not executed until the current callback (`onCreate` of the activity) is complete.

You have a few other places to access your `PreferenceScreen`.  `OnStart` is called when the UI is ready, so the `Fragment` will be ready.  `onResume` is called after `onStart` and is probably the best place to put something since it is invoked after coming back from a pause, too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got stuck calling getPreferenceScreen() in onCreate() method. Now I finally get it worked by calling it in onStart()